# @Inject and @Named annotation giving NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the following Classes implementing LogWriter Interface(

> all are custom classes with these names not the standard java package
>   classes

) inside package com.springprogramming.spring.test.model

```
@Component
public class ConsoleWriter implements LogWriter{    

public void write(String st){
    System.out.println("in Console writer "+st);
}
}

@Component("fileWriter")
public class FileWriter implements LogWriter{   

public void write(String st){
    System.out.println("in Console writer "+st);
}
}

public interface LogWriter {

public  void write(String st);
}

@Component
```

public class Logger {

```
private ConsoleWriter consoleWriter;

private LogWriter fileWriter;


@Inject
public void setConsoleWriter(ConsoleWriter consoleWriter) {
    this.consoleWriter = consoleWriter;
}

@Inject
@Named(value="fileWriter")
public void setFileWriter(LogWriter fileWriter) {
    this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
}

public void writeFile(String text){
    fileWriter.write(text);
}


public void writeConsole(String text){
    if(consoleWriter!=null)
        consoleWriter.write(text);
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    System.out.println("init");
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy(){
    System.out.println("destroy");
}
}
```

I am trying to skip the bean defined in my spring config xml file(app-config.xml), thus using component scan inside my base package:

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.springprogramming.spring.test.model">
</context:component-scan>
```

Now in my main class (App3.java)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/springprogramming/spring/test/beans/app-config.xml");

    Logger logger = (Logger)context.getBean("logger");
    logger.writeConsole("HI ");
    logger.writeFile("Hello");

    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context).close();

}
```

When I run this program , i am getting  error (when I use @Named with @Inject over my setFileWriter method ,i get following exception.
If I remove @Named annotation , it executes fine

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.springprogramming.spring.test.model.LogWriter] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency.

What's wrong with this program?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you do not make the parameter type specific for FileWriter, as the method name already suggests this (in that case you do not need the @Named anymore):

```
public void setFileWriter(FileWriter fileWriter) {
    this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
}
```

If that is not what you want, you should place the `@Named` with the parameter:
    public void setFileWriter(@Named("fileWriter") LogWriter fileWriter) {
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
    }
See also the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations) of Spring.
This is a very unusual way to set the fileWriter, a better approach would be, to inject the FileWriter with the declaration of the field:

```
@Inject
@Named("fileWriter")
private LogWriter fileWriter;
```

I personally find it cleaner to have annotations on the fields instead of the setter methods, as in many cases you do not need an explicit setter method.

Comment: Thanks hotzst for the answer , I am actually learning the annotations and trying experimenting the uses of different annotations. Hence I tried with various combinations on the fields as well and on the setter methods to check its usage :)